# How do I add mxGraph mouse-over and other events to the Google Map example?

Tags: javascript, mxgraph

The [mxgraph](https://github.com/jgraph/mxgraph/) Google Maps [example](https://github.com/jgraph/mxgraph/blob/master/javascript/examples/map.html) (and [demo](https://jgraph.github.io/mxgraph/javascript/examples/map.html)) shows a simple implementation that create a Google Map overlay.

I have managed to add some [georeferenced](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51428641/1491089) mxGraph vertices, but now I can not interact with them.

How do I add mxGraph events (such as a tooltip) to the added vertex?

I copied the `graph.addMouseListener()` implementation from the [hovericons](https://jgraph.github.io/mxgraph/javascript/examples/hovericons.html) example, but the event functions are never called.

Answer (score 1):

I've given up trying to integrate mxGraph and Google Maps. The Google Map component is not an mxGraph component and it does not pass on the events.

mxGraph is for fine editing native components, as per all the other examples, but for map integration, I have found [leaflet.js](https://leafletjs.com/examples/quick-start/) to be much easier to use:

- All co-ordinates are [native GPS latitude/longitude](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51428641/)
- supporting [custom map markers](https://leafletjs.com/examples/custom-icons/),
- [custom popups](https://plnkr.co/edit/QxqvzaIgmONlCo0jirHy?p=preview) (see code fragment, below)
- [drag and drop of markers](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/80306), etc.

```
    var shelter1 = L.marker([55.0, 11.74644]).addTo(map);
    shelter1.bindPopup("<img src='" + picURL2 + "'/>").openPopup();
```